# Programmatic screencapture on mobile device

Tags: android, screenshot

I would like to implement some sort of remote assistance tool (like vnc) for Android. Is there the possibility to capture a screen programmatically on the device?

Answer (score 17):

Something like that might work for you:

```
View v = view.getRootView();
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = v.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed! I had a similar problem but I only wanted a Bitmap of my app, not the OS UI etc

Answer (score 12):

There is a long discussion of this on [android-developers](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers), but the short answer is: You can't programatically take a screenshot of an android device's screen at the moment, unless

1. You have root access on that phone, or
2. Your application is a system application

The Android Manifest permission **READ_FRAME_BUFFER** exists (see the api docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_FRAME_BUFFER)), but can presently only be used by system applications. There are various reasons for this, one being that it is a security risk. If an background can take a screenshot of the phone's screen at any time, then people could use OCR techniques to sniff user's passwords as they were typed in, among other private information.

So no, a VNC application is not possible at the moment without root. To take a screenshot from your computer (while the phone is plugged in via usb) you can use [DDMS](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=android+ddms+take+screenshot).

Comment: Based on what you said here, it sounds like that a system application could be installed via non-stock recovery and not necessarily need to the ROM itself be rooted.  I haven't heard of any VNC system applications, even 1.75 years after you posted this answer.  There are a lot of custom ROM users out there and it seems that there is quite a void there waiting for someone to come along with a good VNC app.

Comment: Regarding point 2: you have to be more than just a system application (i.e. in the system folder), you have to be signed by OS key, which is much more restrictive. This is the difference between a permission being "signatureOrSystem" and "signature".

Answer (score 7):

You can try the following library:
http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/
Android Screenshot Library (ASL) enables to programmatically capture screenshots from Android devices without requirement of having root access privileges. Instead, ASL utilizes a native service running in the background, started via the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) once per device boot.

Comment: Your answer is very useful to me but when i use this library it keep showing me a toast saying "Native service not found". Have you encountered such a problem if so please do help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think its possible in kitkat using the adb command for screen capture.
You can use this command to record screen as a video

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4
```

You can find more details [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#screenrecord)

**you can execute the adb command from your app.**
Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381828/is-it-possible-to-execute-adb-commands-through-my-android-app)

Comment: Nope. After executing: 'screenrecord --verbose --time-limit 5 /sdcard/recvid.mp4' on the getRuntime().exec() method... The process does run, however I get the error: "Permission Denial: broadcast asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACt_ACROSS_USERS_FULL.." However I've been able to run 'screenrecord --help' just fine!

Answer (score 1):

put it in onClick ..

```
Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
saveBitmap(bitmap);
```

and write funtcion..

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
   View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
   rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The VNC-type remote tol does exist for "SOME" android devices (mainly Samsung):

**TeamViewer QuickSupport**
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market

Dos anyone knows how that tool gets screen capturing, and why it supports only limited set of devices?