# launching a service to record current screen in android

Tags: java, android, service, emulation

i need to launch a service running in the background,that should record what's on the current screen for say about 10 sec.. i should able to save it in a file or on any storage device and later i should able to retrieve it also..

plz plz anyone help me, i am running out of my time deadline..

thanks in advance  Manju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this discussion. It seems to be relevant for you.
[Programmatic screencapture on mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582603/programmatic-screencapture-on-mobile-device)

Comment: hi Alex thanks for giving such a great resource but i think the native service in the asl should be made running on the device, manually by connecting the device to a computer for every time when the device rebooted, that's not user friendly for end user's....what do you say..

Comment: can it be made the native service to get started automatically whenever  my device boots up..

Answer (score 0):

Well that's your problem that you're running out of time. As for your question, that's generally not possible. The service has no access to what's displayed on the screen. That would be a huge security issue

Comment: thanks for your reply,as you said i can't use a service for this,do you have any idea on how to accomplish this,and let me know what all the security issue..i think you are saying about rooting the device to make it offer superuser privileges...