# How does all snapshot applications in google play work without device root?

Tags: android, root, google-play, snapshot

There are many applications in google play that take `snapshot`, they work without device root.

Am new to Android development, so I dont know much of what can be done and what can not be and how it's done.

Following is the link on which you can find the list of applications working without device root :-

http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/screen+capture+no+root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the descriptions of those products, you will see phrases like "Rooting will be required depending on model". That is because you are not supposed to be able to take screenshots programmatically, though rooted device users may be able to pull this off, at least for some devices.

Another technique, that at least one such app uses, is to involve a developer computer in the process, using the mechanisms in Android used by DDMS and such for taking screenshots. In reality, it is the computer, not the device, taking the screenshots.

For the devices that such apps work on without requiring root and without requiring a developer computer, the authors of those apps are exploiting security holes in individual devices, just like a malware author would.

Comment: I know that on rooted devices one would need to save framebuffer as an image file but how to convert fb0 to png or jpg image??

Answer (score 1):

Check this [library](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/).

Their page seems to suggest it can take screenshot without root.

> Android Screenshot Library (ASL) enables to programmatically capture
>   screenshots from Android devices without requirement of having root
>   access privileges. Instead, ASL utilizes a native service running in
>   the background, started via the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) once per
>   device boot.

Edit:
there are quite a lot of posts SO regarding this

[Programmatic screencapture on mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582603/programmatic-screencapture-on-mobile-device)
[Screen Capture in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733988/screen-capture-in-android)

Comment: The library in question uses the "involve a developer computer" approach, albeit in a way that does not require the computer to be continuously tethered.

Comment: @CommonsWare Like you said taking screenshots should not be possible, Since it is a security hole. Even if it is possible now, eventually will be closed. Not sure of the libraries, have never tried it.

Comment: I wonder why they could not allow the snapshot capability as a native feature of Android, to ensure that it would only be done under user control.  And/or allow apps to have this ability, but only via an API that involves the user in confirming that the snapshot should be sent to the app in question, and/or only allow apps to have this capability if they do not have Internet access permission.  Security is complicated, so this question may be naive.