# android Screen Capture

Tags: java, android, video, surfaceview, android-videoview

i want to capture the video screen as image from videoview in android..my code is given below.its create the image but that image contains only blackscreen in sdcard.how to capture the videoview as image while playing.

```
public class VidePlayerActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public String fname;
public int n=1;
LinearLayout screen;
Timer timer;
Bitmap bmScreen;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    Button sr=(Button)findViewById(R.id.screenrec);
    screen=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.screen);
    VideoView videoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    videoView.setVideoPath("sdcard/test.mp4");
    MediaController mediaController=new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    sr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    screen.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    bmScreen = screen.getDrawingCache();
                    saveImage(bmScreen);
        }
    });
    }
 protected void saveImage(Bitmap bmpscreen3) {

        //Toast.makeText(ScreenCaptureActivity.this, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        File myDir=new File("/sdcard/Video_images");
          myDir.mkdirs();

           fname = "img"+ n +".jpg";
          File file = new File (myDir, fname);

        try {
            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmpscreen3.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
            ostream.flush();
            ostream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar has already been posted to stackoverflow, check below might help you out.

[Screen Capture in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733988/screen-capture-in-android)

Also one here:

[Programmatic screencapture on mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582603/programmatic-screencapture-on-mobile-device)